# Show that $cd[(c+d)^2-3] > 0$ where $c > 0$ and $d > 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Show that $cd[(c+d)^2-3] > 0$ where $c > 0$ and $d > 0$

Can anyone help me with how to proceed?

Comment: That isn’t necessarily true. Take $c=d=0.5$ for instance. It is true if you mean $c,d$ are integers though.

Comment: This is false. Put $c=d=1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

This is false. Dividing both sides by $cd$ (this is allowed since they're both positive), $$(c+d)^2 -3>0$$ $$\therefore(c+d)^2>3,$$ for which there are many counterexamples. If $c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$, then try using the inequality above and using induction.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out it's false if $c,d \in \mathbb R^+$.

If $c,d \in \mathbb N$ then $cd[(c+d)^2-3] \ge cd[(1+1)^2-3]=cd >0 $.